# Stripe how to cancel other recurring charges when user buys new one

Tags: php, stripe-payments

i'm very new to stripe and i'm stuck on one thing.
i created a product and added three recurring price plans in it named Basic , Standard and Advance

issue is if i buy advance and than i buy standard plan than the advance plan subscription isn't canceled and both subscriptions are active. what i want is when i buy different plan than the old plan's recurring charge subscription get's canceled and i cant figure out how to do that.

[image to list of subscription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/068Ek.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was able to do it here. https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrade-downgrade

stripe had two different docs for upgrade so the other one was not working but this one works well right now